# Error setting up react-native on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I just started learning react native. I am following this tutorial to set up my environment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/178012/react-native-tutorial-building-android-apps-javascript

Everything seems okay until the point where I have to run 'react-native run-android'. I get the error below:

JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine java version from '9.0.4'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
  set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I have both JAVA 8 and 9 installed but I am pointing to Java 8. This is what $JAVA_HOME returns when I echo:

"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"

Note, I have an emulator running too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do what s on this link below as-well: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
This page will help you install and build your first React Native app.
The commands:

```
   $npm install -g create-react-native-app
   $create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
   $cd AwesomeProject
   $npm start
```

(I also tried a Youtube video regarding how to start and run a project on Ubuntu : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZ5nCNOzflM )

I did it myself and for me it worked, at least for what I showed above.

This part is about building projects with React Native:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
Commands :

```
  $npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Install JS needed:

Add the following lines to your $HOME/.bash_profile config file:

> export JAVASCRIPT_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Create project:

> $react-native init AwesomeProject

Run:

```
 $cd AwesomeProject
 $react-native run-android
```

Let me know if I was of any help or not.
I am also trying to integrate Boilerplate for Android using React Native on a Linux Platform (Ubuntu) and I still didn t find a solution to do that, except what I described above. 
Good Luck :)